# How to enable template page only for a post id page

Tags: functions, theme-development, templates, page-template

I wish to limit the possibility to use a specific template page only for post id x

I have created a page-blog.php template and I want it usable only for the post id 115 (id of my blog page).

Actually, in administration, all posts have the template on the models list native metabox, so perhaps we can limit or filter this models list ?

I checked this wordpress page but impossible to achieve my goal by using the slug method =>
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page

Thanks

Comment: You want it applied by default on that page ID or you want the user to manually apply that template?

Comment: I want the user can see this template page on list, only when editing the post id 115

Comment: the blog page would not use that template anyway - it would use index.php or home.php - see https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#home-page-display

Comment: Only if you specified the blog page in reading settings, in my case I don't specified any page as blog page.
As as answered to myself, I have found the correct code solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
    * Filters list of page templates for a theme.
    * @param string[]     $post_templates Array of template header names keyed by the template file name.
    * @param WP_Theme     $this           The theme object.
    * @param WP_Post|null $post           The post being edited, provided for context, or null.
    * @param string       $post_type      Post type to get the templates for.
*/

add_filter('theme_templates', function($post_templates, $this, $post, $post_type){
  // Unless post is 115, filter your custom template from the dropdown.
 if(!empty($post) && $post->ID != '150'){
    return array_filter($post_templates, function($template_name){
        return $template_name !== 'your_template_name';
    });
  }
  return $post_templates;
}, 20, 4);
```

Comment: That's look like very good !
I did little change to call it as function, but my page id 115 don't see the template like other page, so I missed something with the condition ?
Here it's my modified version =>
`code`
function n1_filter_template_pageblog($post_templates, $this, $post, $post_type) {
 // Unless post is 115, filter your custom template from the dropdown.
 if($post->ID != 115){
    return array_filter($post_templates, function($template_name){
        return $template_name !== 'Blog';
    });
  }
}
add_filter('theme_page_templates', 'n1_filter_template_pageblog');`code`

Comment: if a filter uses more than the default amount of arguments(1) you have to specify the number. do it like this: `add_filter('theme_page_templates', 'n1_filter_template_pageblog', 10, 4);`

Comment: Ok fine, it take in consideration my post id, condition is fine.
But result is my post id don't show templates list now (no list, not input, nothing), other id show templates list correctly without the "Blog" template

Comment: Forgot to add the default return at the end. should work now.

Comment: Thanks, now the template list is ok in post id 115, but still filtered like other post id, no presence of my template in the list

Comment: I changed the ID from an integer to a string, that seems to work on my end.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's still don't work, with current code copied pasted (changed id and template_name of course), that's do not filter for my page id, and for other page :/

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do it, based on the fact templates are stored as array (as Himad show me), we can filter this array and remove my template_name with array_diff php function =>

```
 function n1_filter_template_pageblog($post_templates, $this, $post, $post_type) {
    $template_tofiltrate = 'Blog';
    $postid_exception = '115';
    if(get_the_ID() != $postid_exception){
        return array_diff($post_templates, array($template_tofiltrate));
    }
        return $post_templates;
 }
 add_filter('theme_page_templates', 'n1_filter_template_pageblog', 10, 4);
```

This one worked fine for me, all page won't see the template named "Blog" excepted the page with postid 115.